# \footnote within \caption

Tags: pdftex, natbib

I'm trying to cite a caption in the footnotes but when I use bibtex and pdflatex the result does not have any footnotes.
If I use the same footnotes on text it works and automatically generates the caption.

Minimal working example below!

Code:

```
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{Irrigation-Methods.png}
\caption[Classification of Irrigation Methods]{Classification of Irrigation Methods\protect\footnote{test \citep{Soilless}\citep{basak}}}
\label{fig:Irrigation-Methods}
\end{figure}
```

Console Output:

```
Building project: masterarbeit
--------------------------------------------------
Masterarbeit.tex(1): Package typearea Warning: You've used deprecated option `DIV10'.
Masterarbeit.tex(1): Package array Warning: Column w is already defined on input line 138.
Masterarbeit.tex(1): Package scrlayer-scrpage Warning: Command `\setheadwidth' is deprecated.
Masterarbeit.tex(1): Package scrlayer-scrpage Warning: Command deprecated!
Masterarbeit.tex(46): LaTeX Warning: \include should only be used after \begin{document} on input line 46.
Masterarbeit.tex(49): LaTeX Warning: \include should only be used after \begin{document} on input line 49.
Masterarbeit.tex(1): Package scrlayer-scrpage Warning: \headheight to low.
Deckblatt.tex(1): Overfull \vbox (19.60725pt too high) has occurred while \output is active
Masterarbeit.tex(1): Package scrlayer-scrpage Warning: \headheight to low.
Masterarbeit.tex(1): Overfull \vbox (0.86903pt too high) has occurred while \output is active
Masterarbeit.tex(1): Class scrreprt Warning: \float@listhead detected!
Masterarbeit.tex(1): Class scrreprt Warning: \float@addtolists detected!
Masterarbeit.bbl(68): Underfull \hbox (badness 2875) in paragraph at lines 68--68
Masterarbeit.bbl(74): Underfull \hbox (badness 1237) in paragraph at lines 74--74
Masterarbeit.bbl(80): Underfull \hbox (badness 2635) in paragraph at lines 80--80
Erklaerung.tex(8): Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 8--9
Masterarbeit.tex(1): Class scrreprt Warning: You are using `\begin{appendix}...\end{appendix}'.
Masterarbeit.tex(1): Package natbib Warning: Citation(s) may have changed.
--------------------------------------------------
masterarbeit - 0 error(s), 14 warning(s), 2 overfull box(es), 4 underfull box(es)
```

Log: https://pastebin.com/LqZpm3FD

packages : https://pastebin.com/CPGqD93P

page config: https://pastebin.com/MVTrf0m7

Edit: Minimal Working Example

```
\documentclass[
    11pt, 
    DIV10,
    ngerman,
    a4paper,
    oneside,
    titlepage, 
    parskip=half,
    headings=normal,
    listof=totoc,
    bibliography=totoc,
    index=totoc,
    captions=tableheading,
    final
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[pdftex,final]{graphicx}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{name.png}
\caption[Name]{Name\footnote{test \citep{test}}}
\label{fig:name}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: the method of protecting the footnote does not work. but replacing the \footnote with  \footnotemark and then later additionally writing \footnotetext works.

why doesnt \footnote work with protect ?